# lftp upload files inside different folders

Tags: ftp, lftp

I need to upload files in different folders with same name, recursively to a remote folder. Here a example.

```
Local
   |-app1-1  
   |      |-src
   |      |-img
   |      |-static
   |          |-app1-2      <------Upload from this
   |              |-file1-1
   |              |-file1-2
   |-app2-1  
   |      |-src
   |      |-img
   |      |-static
   |          |-app2-2      <------Upload from this
   |              |-file2-1
   |              |-file2-2
```

Here the remote result I need.

```
Remote Result
   |-folder1
   |-folder2
   |-folder3
   |-static
   |    |-app1-2      <------Upload from this
   |    |     |-file1-1
   |    |     |-file1-2
   |    |  
   |    |-app2-2      <------Upload from this
   |    |     |-file2-1
   |    |     |-file2-1
```

I have testing with scripts like this:

```
  - >
  lftp
  -e "mirror
  --include ^static/
  --exclude ^\.git.*
  -eRv $CI_PROJECT_DIR Remote Result/static; quit;"
  sftp://$CREDENTIALS
```

But this generate a output not desired:

```
Remote Result
  |-folder1
  |-folder2
  |-folder3
  |-static
  |    |-app1-1      <------Upload from this
  |    |     |-static
  |    |         |-app1-2
  |    |            |-file1
  |    |            |-file2

  ...... (Same other folder)
```